# selenium findElement By.cssSelector for multiple classes

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

I am new to `selenium`.

How do search for an element with multiple classes and value.

```
<div class="md-tile-text--primary md-text">Getting Started</div>
```

using findElement By `.css` Selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the node:

```
div class="md-tile-text--primary md-text">Getting Started
```

You can use the following `cssSelector`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.md-tile-text--primary.md-text"));
```

To construct a `cssSelector` based on the text `Getting Started` you can use:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:contains('Getting Started')"));
```

Comment: Thanks Debanjan, How to also select based on text value in the above case "Getting Started"

Comment: will do deb, but still looking for a solution for the above question

Comment: Thanks deb that worked, only need to how know how to include the text "Getting Started" in the criteria

Comment: Thanks Deb, i am unable to vote now as i dont have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.md-tile-text--primary.md-text"));

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:contains('Getting Started')")); How to combine both the above statements into one?